# How to animate this 3D plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, mesh, matlab-figure

My current code :

```
a=7
f=10
T=1/f;
v=40
wl=v/f;
x1=1;
x2=30
step=0.01

t=x1:step:x2;
x=x1:step:x2;
y=a*sind(2*pi*f*(t+(x*T)/wl)); 
h=plot3(x,y,t);
set(h,'EraseMode','xor','MarkerSize',20)
xlabel('displacement(m)');
ylabel('amplitude(m)');
title('Wave Animation');
for t=x1:step:x2
drawnow
y=a*sind(2*pi*f*(t+(x*T)/wl)); 
set(h,'YData',y)
pause(0.01)
end
```

I converted it to a 3D mesh plot but it takes ages to render in animation and Matlab crashes.

```
a=7
f=10
T=1/f;
v=40
wl=v/f;
x1=1;
x2=30
step=0.01

t=x1:step:x2;
x=x1:step:x2;
[x,t] = meshgrid(x,t);
y     = a*sind(2*pi*f*(t+(x*T)/wl)); 
mesh(y)
```

What's the best way to animate this so that it looks similar to what I have before making it 3D ?

Comment: You need to calculate y inside the loop and make it dependent on j or nothing will ever change.

Comment: @shoelzer I got it to work, thanks. However it renders slowly while it stores info in F, how can prevent it from showing before `Movie(F)` is used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't animate this in real time, an easy alternative is using [getframe](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) and [movie](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html). You use `getframe` to capture frames at whatever rate you can generate them, then use `movie` to replay the frames at a faster frame rate. See the `getframe` link for a simple example.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. However it renders slowly while it stores info in F, how can prevent it from showing before `Movie(F)` is used ?

Comment: @NLed I don't think you can prevent it from showing. The frames have to be drawn to be captured.